# Software for genomics/bioinformatics server development - Open Source

Tags: open-source, web-apps, java, node.js

I'm in a quandry - I have a Masters project (bioinformatics) next year and I have to choose a framework for developing a website/processing centre/general allround functionality. Open Source is an absolute **must**.

Criteria:

- look reasonably good (not a **huge** priority)
- capable of heavy-duty processing - i.e. performing phylogenetic analyses/drawing trees - this is **extremely** computationally intensive.
- be able to perform ad-hoc queries against a PostgreSQL database and/or databases on the web using REST interfaces.
- be able to perform multi-server work eventually

I'm thinking the **Java** ecosphere or **node.js**

I'd be interested in ideas/opinions/references/URLS/whatever on the pros and cons of both frameworks for a general purpose web-development environment, capable of heavy-hitting when necessary! I know that Java can be used for processing intensive work - but I have read that Javascript is not suited for this - good for presentation but not heavy-lifting. Does node.js change this?

If I have to learn something, I would prefer to use the same language both server- and client-side, but the processing capabilities take priority!

Comment: "capable of heavy-duty processing": The kind of processing that runs for weeks on a distributed cluster? If so, you would be better off first choosing a heavy-duty processing tool with a integration-friendly web UI, and *then* choosing a web framework that can show it, for instance as an IFrame portlet in Liferay.

Comment: Could you please edit the title? It is far too generic, and does not reflect the gist of the question. Thanks! :-)

Comment: Please also replace "general allround functionality" with more specific examples.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul - have edited my question. I hope this clarifies matters?

Comment: Do you want the extremely computationally intensive tasks to be performed on several computers? Or only on the same computer that is also being used as a web server? All web servers have a "time out" of a few minutes. This timeout can be configured, but configuring it to hours is often not a supported use case.

Comment: Maybe my question should be more: Is javascript on node.js suitable for heavy processing requirements? I thought that javascript wasn't geared towards heavy lifting - great for presentation but not processing. I hadn't thought about multiple nodes - it'll have to be a yes on the multiple nodes - cloud/Hadoop/Apache ecosphere a big part of course - thanks. I have edited the question accordingly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest taking a close look at the [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) or [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) - both are:

- python based,
- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Rapid prototyping and development
- Cross platform
- Have very helpful & active communites
- Can produce **very** good looking web sites take a look at Public Broadcasting Service, Instagram, Mozilla, The Washington Times, Disqus, Bitbucket, and Nextdoor *all Django based* or Pinterest *Flask*.
- Being python based you can use and interface with the rest of the python ecosystem with tools such as SciPy, Pandas, Jupyter, [Biopython](http://biopython.org/)
- There is a wealth of tools & literature for bioinformatics & geographic information systems in Python.